# io.swagger.inflector.examples.ExampleBuilder.fromProperty() gives all information of the model definition

Tags: java, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to get an example from swagger file using ExampleBuilder.fromProperty

Below is the library which I have used

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-inflector</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Below is the output which i'm getting

```
{
    "name": "InitiatePaymentRequest",
    "namespace": null,
    "prefix": null,
    "attribute": false,
    "wrapped": false,
    "wrappedName": null,
    "typeName": "object",
    "values": {
        "beneficiaryInformation": {
            "name": "BeneficiaryInformation",
            "namespace": null,
            "prefix": null,
            "attribute": false,
            "wrapped": false,
            "wrappedName": null,
            "typeName": "object",
            "values": {
                "destinationAccountIdentifier": {
                    "name": "destinationAccountIdentifier",
                    "namespace": null,
                    "prefix": null,
                    "attribute": false,
                    "wrapped": false,
                    "wrappedName": null,
                    "typeName": "string",
                    "value": "string"
                },
                "destinationBankIdentifier": {
                    "name": "destinationBankIdentifier",
                    "namespace": null,
                    "prefix": null,
                    "attribute": false,
                    "wrapped": false,
                    "wrappedName": null,
                    "typeName": "string",
                    "value": "DEUTDEDB237"
                },
                "fullName": {
                    "name": "fullName",
                    "namespace": null,
                    "prefix": null,
                    "attribute": false,
                    "wrapped": false,
                    "wrappedName": null,
                    "typeName": "string",
                    "value": "JASON SMITH"
                }
            }
        },
        "purposeOfPayment": {
            "name": "purposeOfPayment",
            "namespace": null,
            "prefix": null,
            "attribute": false,
            "wrapped": false,
            "wrappedName": null,
            "typeName": "string",
            "value": "Invoice Payment"
        },
        "remittanceInformation": {
            "name": "remittanceInformation",
            "namespace": null,
            "prefix": null,
            "attribute": false,
            "wrapped": false,
            "wrappedName": null,
            "typeName": "string",
            "value": "Mantainance of Fixtures"
        },
        "remitterInformation": {
            "name": "RemitterInformation",
            "namespace": null,
            "prefix": null,
            "attribute": false,
            "wrapped": false,
            "wrappedName": null,
            "typeName": "object",
            "values": {
                "sourceAccountCurrency": {
                    "name": "sourceAccountCurrency",
                    "namespace": null,
                    "prefix": null,
                    "attribute": false,
                    "wrapped": false,
                    "wrappedName": null,
                    "typeName": "string",
                    "value": "EUR"
                },
                "sourceAccountIdentifier": {
                    "name": "sourceAccountIdentifier",
                    "namespace": null,
                    "prefix": null,
                    "attribute": false,
                    "wrapped": false,
                    "wrappedName": null,
                    "typeName": "string",
                    "value": "string"
                },
                "sourceBankIdentifier": {
                    "name": "sourceBankIdentifier",
                    "namespace": null,
                    "prefix": null,
                    "attribute": false,
                    "wrapped": false,
                    "wrappedName": null,
                    "typeName": "string",
                    "value": "DEUTDEDBFRA"
                }
            }
        },
        "transferAmount": {
            "name": "transferAmount",
            "namespace": null,
            "prefix": null,
            "attribute": false,
            "wrapped": false,
            "wrappedName": null,
            "typeName": "decimal",
            "value": 1.5
        },
        "transferCurrency": {
            "name": "transferCurrency",
            "namespace": null,
            "prefix": null,
            "attribute": false,
            "wrapped": false,
            "wrappedName": null,
            "typeName": "string",
            "value": "EUR"
        },
        "transferDate": {
            "name": "transferDate",
            "namespace": null,
            "prefix": null,
            "attribute": false,
            "wrapped": false,
            "wrappedName": null,
            "typeName": "string",
            "value": "2015-07-20"
        },
        "transferType": {
            "name": "transferType",
            "namespace": null,
            "prefix": null,
            "attribute": false,
            "wrapped": false,
            "wrappedName": null,
            "typeName": "string",
            "value": "SCTInst"
        },
        "uniqueRequestNo": {
            "name": "uniqueRequestNo",
            "namespace": null,
            "prefix": null,
            "attribute": false,
            "wrapped": false,
            "wrappedName": null,
            "typeName": "string",
            "value": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Below is my expected output:

```
{
    "beneficiaryInformation": {
        "destinationAccountIdentifier": "string",
        "destinationBankIdentifier": "DEUTDEDB237",
        "fullName": "JASON SMITH"
    },
    "purposeOfPayment": "Invoice Payment",
    "remittanceInformation": "Mantainance of Fixtures",
    "remitterInformation": {
        "sourceAccountCurrency": "EUR",
        "sourceAccountIdentifier": "string",
        "sourceBankIdentifier": "DEUTDEDBFRA"
    },
    "transferAmount": 1.5,
    "transferCurrency": "EUR",
    "transferDate": "2015-07-20",
    "transferType": "SCTInst",
    "uniqueRequestNo": "string"
}
```

Need some suggestion on how to achieve the same..Thanks

I'm trying to get an example from swagger file using ExampleBuilder.fromProperty

Here is my model definition

```
"InitiatePaymentRequest": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "beneficiaryInformation": {
      "description": "the details of the beneficiary",
      "$ref": "#/definitions/BeneficiaryInformation"
    },
    "purposeOfPayment": {
      "type": "string",
      "example": "Invoice Payment",
      "description": "the purpose for which the payment is being made",
      "minLength": 0,
      "maxLength": 35,
      "pattern": "[A-Z0-9a-z?:().,'+/\\- ]*"
    },
    "remittanceInformation": {
      "type": "string",
      "example": "Mantainance of Fixtures",
      "description": "a free text that may be received by the beneficiary",
      "minLength": 0,
      "maxLength": 140,
      "pattern": "[A-Z0-9a-z?:().,'+/\\- ]*"
    },
    "remitterInformation": {
      "description": "the details of the remitter",
      "$ref": "#/definitions/RemitterInformation"
    },
    "transferAmount": {
      "type": "number",
      "example": 123.01,
      "description": "the amount to transfer",
      "minimum": 0,
      "exclusiveMinimum": true
    },
    "transferCurrency": {
      "type": "string",
      "example": "EUR",
      "description": "the currency for the transfer amount",
      "enum": [
        "EUR"
      ]
    },
    "transferDate": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date",
      "description": "the date for the transfer, should always be the current business date"
    },
    "transferType": {
      "type": "string",
      "example": "SCTInst",
      "description": "the payment network to be used for the transfer",
      "enum": [
        "SCTInst"
      ]
    },
    "uniqueRequestNo": {
      "type": "string",
      "description": "a unique value that is used to identify each distinct request",
      "minLength": 1,
      "maxLength": 35,
      "pattern": "[A-Z0-9a-z]*"
    }
  },
  "title": "InitiatePaymentRequest"
}
```

And below is my java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Swagger swagger = new SwaggerParser()
            .read("swagger.json");
    swagger.getPaths().size();

    swagger.getPaths().forEach((k, v) -> {
        GenPactRequest req = new GenPactRequest();
        req.setName(swagger.getInfo().getTitle());

        v.getOperationMap().forEach((a, b) -> {
            SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule().addSerializer(new JsonNodeExampleSerializer());
            Json.mapper().registerModule(simpleModule);

            List<Parameter> body = b.getParameters();

            ApiRequest apiReq = new ApiRequest();
            req.setDescription(b.getSummary());
            req.setProvider(b.getSummary());
            req.setApiCode("sdf23e3r");
            apiReq.setPath(k);
            apiReq.setMethod(a.toString());

            // operation is GET, with no input
            if (body.size() == 0) {
                req.setRequest(writeValueAsString(mapper, apiReq));
                b.getResponses().forEach((x, y) -> {
                    if (x == "200") {
                        req.setResponse(writeValueAsString(mapper,
                                responseBody(req, x, b, mapper, swagger, y.getSchema())));
                    }
                });
                log.info(writeValueAsString(mapper, req));
                return;
            }

            // api with GET/POST, with path-param/body
            for (Parameter parameter : body) {
                // api with POST, with body
                if (parameter instanceof BodyParameter) {

                    BodyParameter bp = (BodyParameter) parameter;

                    apiReq.setBody(Json.pretty(ExampleBuilder.fromProperty(
                            new RefProperty(bp.getSchema().getReference()), swagger.getDefinitions())));
                    req.setRequest(writeValueAsString(mapper, apiReq));
                    b.getResponses().forEach((x, y) -> {
                        if (x == "200") {
                            req.setResponse(writeValueAsString(mapper,
                                    responseBody(req, x, b, mapper, swagger, y.getSchema())));
                        }
                    });
                    log.info(writeValueAsString(mapper, req));
                    return;
                }

                // api with GET, with path param
                else if (parameter instanceof PathParameter) {
                    req.setRequest(writeValueAsString(mapper, apiReq));
                }

                b.getResponses().forEach((x, y) -> {
                    if (x == "200") {
                        req.setResponse(writeValueAsString(mapper,
                                responseBody(req, x, b, mapper, swagger, y.getSchema())));
                    }
                });
                log.info(writeValueAsString(mapper, req));
                return;

            }
        });

    });

}


 private static ApiResponse responseBody(GenPactRequest req, String status, Operation op, ObjectMapper mapper,
        Swagger swagger, Property property) {
    ApiResponse apiRes = new ApiResponse();
    apiRes.setStatus(Integer.valueOf(status));
    ApiResponseHeader header = new ApiResponseHeader();
    header.setHeaders(op.getProduces().get(0));
    apiRes.setHeaders(header);
    apiRes.setBody(Json.pretty(ExampleBuilder.fromProperty(property, swagger.getDefinitions())));

    return apiRes;
 }

 private static String writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper mapper, Object obj) {
    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        log.info("Unable to convert into json");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

 }
```

Comment: Please post your Java code and the model definition from the Swagger file.

Comment: updated the question with java code and model definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found the work around:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(Json.pretty(ExampleBuilder.fromProperty(
                            new RefProperty(bp.getSchema().getReference()), 
swagger.getDefinitions())));

apiReq.setBody(obj.toMap());
```

which gives me the expected output..

Comment: Hi @hello1693, I am also facing exactly same issue, so pls share all the imports for GenPactReq, ApiRequest, etc, are these classes internal to your org.? if not pls share import details as well as the complete code if possible, thanks in advance, keep helping

Comment: Thanks, I've found the answer, : D which is almost similar to yours, I just followed this link: https://csoco.wordpress.com/tag/swagger-2-0/ and resolved my issue